# Adding To an XMLSchemaSet from a Pack URI

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net, uri

I'm trying to add to an XMLSchemaSet from a pack URI and I'm getting the following error:

Exception thrown: 'System.NotSupportedException' in System.dll

Additional information: The URI prefix is not recognized.

Here's the code:

```
Dim XML = XDocument.Parse("<Product></Product>")
Dim Schemas As New XmlSchemaSet()
Schemas.Add("", "pack://application:,,,/MyAssemblyName;component/Resources/XSD Resources/Product.xsd")
XML.Validate(Schemas, Sub(sender As Object, e As ValidationEventArgs) Console.WriteLine(e.Message))
```

I don't have any problems loading from local path, but these XSDs need to be packaged with the application.  What am I doing wrong with the pack URI here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify a custom [`XmlResolver`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.schema.xmlschemaset.xmlresolver(v=vs.110).aspx) and provide an implementation that knows how to load "pack:" URIs:

```vb
Dim XML = XDocument.Parse("<Product></Product>")
Dim Schemas As New XmlSchemaSet()
Schemas.XmlResolver = New CustomResolver()
Schemas.Add("", "pack://application:,,,/MyAssemblyName;component/Resources/XSD Resources/Product.xsd")
XML.Validate(Schemas, Sub(sender As Object, e As ValidationEventArgs) Console.WriteLine(e.Message))
' ...
Class CustomResolver
    Inherits XmlUrlResolver

    Public Overrides Function GetEntity(absoluteUri As Uri, role As String, ofObjectToReturn As Type) As Object
        If absoluteUri.Scheme = "pack" Then
            Return Application.GetResourceStream(absoluteUri).Stream
        End If
        Return MyBase.GetEntity(absoluteUri, role, ofObjectToReturn)
    End Function

End Class
```

This is only minimally tested, so you may need to add some error handling, etc.